# nginx can't link uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have installed nginx successfully and uwsgi work well but when I want to link nginx with uwsgi.it's wrong
This is my nginx.conf and uwsgi.ini

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    #charset koi8-r;
    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

and

```
http=127.0.0.1:8000
#socket=/root/project/learning_log/nginx_uwsgi.socket
chdir=/root/project/learning_log/
#chmod-socket=664
master=true
processes=4
threads=2
module=learning_log.wsgi
#wsgi-file=uwsgi_test.py
#stats=127.0.0.1:8000
```

./nginx & uwsgi3 --ini /root/project/learning_log/uwsgi.ini

when I access 127.0.0.1,it's wrong
and the access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2018:18:06:13 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 504 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
```

the error.log:

```
2018/01/15 18:06:13 [error] 12986#0: *13 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: What do you mean it's wrong?

Comment: can you post uwsgi or nginx log.

Comment: thank you and i have post nginx log@advay.umare